# Prestashop 1.6, abort add to cart product when condition

Tags: php, conditional-statements, cart, prestashop-1.6

I want to create function where addition product to cart will be aborted (with message) when product met the condition (specific category). Where should i put condition code? I try to find method responsible for adding product to cart but i cant find it :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1.6 core method responsible for adding product to cart is processChangeProductInCart() in /controllers/front/CartController.php

Comment: Thanks, i got it. Now i'm trying to figure how go assign all product's categories from cart to array, i need to check if adding product is not exluded witch other by category.

Comment: It's easy. When you have `$product` object `$categories = $product->getCategories();` will return array contains product's categories Id's